# Hide other elements with same class name when one is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I have 10 html divs with same class name "dp-check" which i am using as a component 
and used at lots of time in the same page. Now my problem is initially all divs are hidden when i clicks one of them then its "display" is set to "inline"(only of that instance) and all others are hidden, I want to close when any other div with same class name is shown or somewhere else on page is clicked.

Comment: How can you click an element which is not visible?

Comment: Show us your code as well, can help much better if you show us what you have tried (HTML, CSS, JS).

Comment: i have one layout(div class="toggle") on the top of div("dp-check"), on click of layout(div class="toggle") the div("dp-check") is toggled. but i want to hide it on click anywhere else on the page too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function clickHandler(e){
    e = e || window.event;
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('dp-check');
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        elements[i].style.display = 'none'; // Hide all elements.
    }
    e.target.style.display = 'inline'; // Show the clicked element.
}
```

You'll have to assign the `clickHandler` to the click events on the elements.

Comment: doing some modifications it worked like charm..thanks man..

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help!

Answer (score -1):

You can hide all `dp-check` divs when somewhere else on the page is clicked with jQuery:

```
$('body').click(function (event) {
  var $target = $(event.target);
  if(!$target.hasClass("dp-check") ) {
    $("dp-check").css('display','none');
  }
}
```